# Woocommerce if term is in product title then echo "***"

Tags: php, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Hi i'm trying to implement code that says if product title ( or even product description) has 'crepe' then echo a review. I've attached an attempt but it doesn't work. Ive also tried with `term_exists` and tried to `get_title` but I cant seem to figure it out. Can anyone help me? Thanks!

`function crepe_review () {
global $product;

```
if ( ! $product ) {
    return;
}

$product_id = $product->get_id();



if ( has_term( 'crepe', $product_id ) ) {
        echo '<p>*****</p>';
    
}
```

}

add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'crepe_review', 34 );`

Comment: A _term_ is an additional object connected to your post, it has nothing to do with the actual post _title_.

Comment: You want to figure out if one string contains another one - and that is not the job of `has_term`. How it is actually done, should be easy enough to research.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've tried this: 

`function crepe_review() {
 global $product;

 if ( ! $product ) {
  return;
 }

 $word = "crepe";
 $product_id = $product->get_name();



 if(strpos($product_id, $word) !== false){
    echo "*****";
} 
  
 }





add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'crepe_review', 34 );`

I've tried `get_title` and `get_id` but still no success?